# Parse.com How to get all user's related data

Tags: ios, macos, parse-platform, swift2

I have an app where I'm trying to load a User and all his related data. In the relations I have BodyTracking as one relation. Another is DiaryWeek, which in turn has DiaryDays (of the week).
I successfully pulled all the BodyTracking, but when I try the same for the DiaryWeeks, I get an error saying that I have to wait. I guess what is happening is that the BodyTracking, which is requested with 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' is still going on when the DiaryWeek request is called.
Is there a way to pull all the data in one go?

```
        // Body Tracking
    bodyEntries.removeAll()
    let trackingQuery = PFQuery(className: "BodyTracking")
    trackingQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: member)
    trackingQuery.orderByDescending("trackingDate")
    trackingQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) body entries.")

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    let bodyEntry = BodyTracking(object: object)
                    self.bodyEntries.append(bodyEntry)
                }
                self.bodyTrackingTableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    // Food Diary
    foodWeeks.removeAll()
    let diaryQuery = PFQuery(className: "FoodDiaryWeek")
    diaryQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: member)
    diaryQuery.orderByDescending("weekStartDate")
    trackingQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) food weeks")

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    let foodWeek = FoodDiaryWeek(object: object)
                    self.foodWeeks.append(foodWeek)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Error message: This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are accidentally executing the `trackingQuery` twice. The `diaryQuery` is never executed. Maybe a copy/paste error (?)

```
   // Food Diary
foodWeeks.removeAll()
let diaryQuery = PFQuery(className: "FoodDiaryWeek")
diaryQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: member)
diaryQuery.orderByDescending("weekStartDate")
**trackingQuery**.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
```

replace trackingQuery by diaryQuery